# Get Handler Abstraction

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, get, abstraction

I was reading up on how [to clean up post functions](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/06/22/cleaning-up-posts-in-asp-net-mvc/) and the idea seems very useful. I added onto the idea of an `IFormHandler` by adding a couple more methods and making the class abstract.

```
public abstract class FormHandler<T>
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork unit;

    public FormHandler(UnitOfWork unit)
    {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    protected UnitOfWork Unit
    {
        get
        {
            return this.unit;
        }
    }

    public virtual void PreValidation(ModelStateDictionary modelState, T form)
    {

    }

    public abstract void Handle(T form);

    public virtual void OnValidationFailure(T form)
    {

    }
}
```

This works excellent for post functions and my controllers are alot lighter and easier to understand. I wanted to clean up the GET functions as well. Has anyone already attempted this or have any ideas of how to make the GET functions cleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the [IQueryProcessor pattern mentioned here](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92). Steven also has a good article on [implementing an ICommandHandler interface](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91), similar to what you've done, though with dependency injection rather than an abstract class with inherited methods.